# jquery accordion animate no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-easing

I have have the following code,

```
$("#nav").accordion({
                event: "mouseover",
                autoHeight: false,
                collapsible: false,
                animate: 'bounceslide',
                <?php
                //  Checks for active page and opens the related tab
                    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                    switch($uri):
                        case '/anti-social-behavior-logging':
                            echo('active: 0,'); break;
                        case '/telehealth-services':
                            echo('active: 1,'); break;
                        case '/telecare-services':
                            echo('active: 2,'); break;
                        case '/lone-worker-safety-services':
                            echo('active: 3,'); break;
                        case '/repairs-reporting-services':
                            echo('active: 4,'); break;
                        default:
                            echo('active: 5,');
                    endswitch;
                ?>              
            });
```

However I get the following error,

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'bounceslide'

Why is this? You can see the problem at http://www.astraline.co.uk - As far as I am aware I have all the libraries I need for this to work.

Comment: jQuery UI does not support a `bounceslide` easing function out of the box. Is that a custom easing function?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to put `animated` instead of `animate`.

See: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion/accordion#option-animated

Comment: The animated option was changed to animate in v1.9: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#rewrote-all-easing-equations-to-only-rely-on-state